# SIP реализация на C++

Tags: c++, sip

Нужна реализация протокола SIP на С/С++. Нашел только на Java. 
SIP это открытый протокол аналог Skype.

Comment: посмотри в сторону pjsip или asterisk chan sip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Советую посмотреть [FreeSwitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/). Это большая библиотека с открытым исходным кодом написанная на С++ для телефонии.

Comment: В основе FreeSwitch лежить Sofia SIP созданный в недрах компании Nokia. Возможно это немного ускорит Ваш поиск.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте PJSIP http://www.pjsip.org/ Библиотека написана на С++. Документация хорошая.

Comment: Библиотека PJSIP написана на С для встраиваемых устройств, т.е. имеет специфичный код оптимизированный для работы на микроконтроллерах.